# Email form when an item is submitted

Tags: nintex-workflow

I am new to Nintex. How can I send the form user submitted in the email after he/she hits submit button?

I tried to to create a workflow, but it just sends email without content.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the item URL in the body your email - the link will take them back to the item/form that they just submitted

or

you can use the lookups to insert the fields on your email

Answer (score 0):

/* 
 * This function sends an email when a specific Google Sheets column is edited
 * The spreadsheets triggers must be set to onEdit for this function to work
 */

function sendNotification() {
    //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1N6dqSXs8hdhCi1vrOGT7I7tD2yDMtgK7BSddMPqmuo0');
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    //Get Active cell
    var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
    var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
    var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
    //Define Notification Details for vars

```
var recipients = "joseph@XXXXX.com,jmang@XXXXX.com";
var recipients1 = "joseph2@XXXXX.com"

var subject = "NEW SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST REQUIRES APPROVAL";
var subject1 = "ALERT: SENSITIVE DATA REQUEST";
var body = ss.getName() + " has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";

//Check to see which column will trigger the email - this script sends an email to "var recipients" if 
//column 5 is updated and sends and email to "var recipients1" when colum 7 is updated.

if (cellcol == 5) {
    //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients"
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
}

if (cellcol == 7) {
    //Send the Email to recipients defined in "var recipients1"
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients1, subject1, body);
}

//End sendNotification
```

}